# Permission denied for loging using django mod_wsgi when running multiple domains

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm running two local domains under one apache installation my virualhost is as following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIDaemonProcess staging python-path=/var/www/staging/src/ipinfra/ipinfra:/var/www/staging/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup staging
...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIDaemonProcess ipinfra python-path=/var/www/dev/src/ipinfra/ipinfra:/var/www/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup ipinfra
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works fine just for the staging environment not able to to write log to the logs folder.
Both the application have same permission and same code but staging is unable to write code.

Django app is running under user **ipinfra** and its a member of group **apache**

logs folder has a permission of **766** and log file has **777** permission on both setup.

Comment: Is the first ``WSGIProcessGroup`` meant to have an argument of 'staging', not 'dev'? How is it that the app is running under user 'ipinfra'? You don't specify a user/group for ``WSGIDaemonProcess``. Without that, it would inherit whatever the Apache user is for the whole of Apache. You mean to say the application directories are owned by 'ipinfra'?

Comment: My mistake fixed the typo.

Yes Application directories are owned by user ipinfra which is member of apache group.

Comment: What is the exact error message and where is it shown.

Comment: I have an folder called logs in my app root directory, for both of application i.e. dev.example.com and staging.example.com.   
dev.example.com points to second virtualhost and staging.exmaple.com points to first virtualhost.   

In my project I do create logs and folders per app basis while dev.example.com creates those works but staging.example.com fails to create those folders and files. It gives permission denied error.   

I feel its because `WSGIProcessGroup`  as its name is ipifnra and the user which runs project is also `ipinfra`

Comment: I wanted to see the exact error message and traceback so I could see the context in the code and what the actual file path is that it is trying to access. As I said above, the running code is running as the Apache user, not the user 'ipinfra' which owns the code and directories. Why don't you try adding ``user=ipinfra`` to ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` to have running code actually run as ``ipinfra`` if that is the name of the UNIX user. Does that allow it to work?